Random walk on $\mathbb Z^d$,prove that all states are of the same type (recurrent or transient).
Let $\xi_1..\xi_n..$ be i.i.d. taking values in $\mathbb Z^d$ and distributed according to $\mu$.Define:$$Y_n=Y_0+\sum_{i=1}^n\xi_i$$Where $(\xi_n)_{n\in \mathbb Z_+}$ are independent of $Y_0$.
Then we can verify that $(Y_n)_{n\in \mathbb Z_+}$ is a Markov chain with transition matrix $Q(x,y)=\mu(y-x)$.

Question:How can I verify that either $\forall x\in E$,$x$ is
recurrent or $\forall x\in E$,$x$ is transient

Some attempt:
(1)My textbook writes:"$Q(x,y)=\mu(y-x)$ only depends on $y-x$,it follows that $U(x,y)$ is also a function of $y-x$.Since $x$ is recurrent if and only if $U(x,x)=\infty$.We get that all states are of the same type (recurrent or transient)"
But I have trouble understanding why one can conclude the result from the fact that "$Q(x,y)=\mu(y-x)$ only depends on $y-x$".
(2)I try to prove that $(Y_n)_{n\in \mathbb Z_+}$ is irreducible then use Classification of States of Markov chain.But I am stuck at proving that:$$U(x,y)=\sum_{n\ge 1}Q_n(x,y)\overset?>0$$
Any help would be appreciated.

Note:This problem comes from Measure Theory, Probability, and Stochastic Processes (Jean-François Le Gall) p322


For an irreducible Markov chain this is always true (not just for a random walk).

The property of a random walk to be either a recurrent or a transient one is uniform among all states.
My attempt:
The main insight is that the probability of the transition just depends on the difference between the states. Here's the function $Q(x,y) = \mu(y-x)$. Therefore, this symmetry of translation differentiation will have a big impact.
Green's function,
$$U(x,y) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} Q^n(x,y)$$
is the expected number of visits to state $y$ from state $x$. The property of $Q(x,y)$ which is f(y-x) allows us to see clearly that the $n$-step transition probabilities, $Q^n(x,y)$, also do so and they depend only on $y-x$. So, in turn, $U(x,y)$ must also be a function of the difference $y-x$. Alternatively,
$$U(x,y) = V(y-x)$$
stands for some $V.$
Now analyze $U(x,x)$, which determines whether a state is recurrent or transient. Thus, we are dealing with the equation in its simplest form:
$$U(x,x) = V(x-x) = V(0)$$
This reveals the fact that this value is a constant by moving along x, thus meaning the recurrence/transience feature is the same for all states. Either all $U(x,x)$ are infinite, which means that all states are recurrent if they are finite or they will all be in the transient which means that they are transient are the cases for every state. No one can be recurrent while others are on a transient.
The argument is not based on showing the irreducibility. This is a dominant decision rule, but besides that, since the translation invariance is the true cause for homogeneity in the uniformity/transience of the process. We do not need to check the existence of irreducibility through $U(x,y)>0$, it is just another way of proving it since we already have direct proof.

I am still confused about why we can write $Q^n(x,y)=V(y-x)$ which only depends on $(y-x)$.For instance,$n=2$,$Q^2(x,y)=\sum_{z\in \mathbb Z^d}Q(x,z)Q(z,y)=\sum_{z\in \mathbb Z^d}\mu(z-x)\mu(y-z)\overset?=V(y-x)$ it still seems not obvious to me.

@QoAo The case when there is no cycle, $Q(x,y) = \mu(y-x)$, is given. In the case of the two-step transition, the following statement is true $Q^2(x,y) = \sum_z Q(x,z)Q(z,y)$. The previous definition is used to come up with a new one as follows: $\sum_z \mu(z-x)\mu(y-z)$. One can switch the variables and apply the formula $v = z-x$, then $\sum_v \mu(v)\mu(y-x-v)$ arises. The sum is no longer over $z$ but over $v$, means the parameters become quite explicit.

This generalizes. Assume $Q^n(x,y)$ depends only on $y-x$ (induction hypothesis). Then, $Q^{n+1}(x,y) = \sum_z Q^n(x,z)Q(z,y)$. By the hypothesis, $Q^n(x,z) = f_n(z-x)$ for some function $f_n$. Substituting, we have $\sum_z f_n(z-x)\mu(y-z)$. Again, setting $v = z-x$, the expression becomes $\sum_v f_n(v)\mu(y-x-v)$. The sum is over $v$, and the expression depends only on $y-x$. This shows $Q^{n+1}(x,y)$ also only depends on $y-x$.

Thus by means of induction, we conclude that $Q^n(x,y)$ is always a function of $y-x$. Now the point to be mentioned here is that the process depends only on the difference (in the states) and though the variables become substitutes, this fact aids us to depict all the transitions in terms of that difference.

Oops!I did't realize changing variable $v=z-x$ would help.Thank you for your time!
